# WYSIHTML5 - Where are the default iFrame settings?

Tags: css, iframe, wysihtml5

I want to change the default padding for my wysihtml5 text area, however I keep going through the docs and the files and I cannot seem to find where it is set. It currently has a 54px padding on the left I would like to remove. CTRL-F in all of the files in the github doesn't find 54 anywhere...Where is that being set? It's inline or I'd override it with a css rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could reset all padding to 0 by adding this at the top of your css:

```
*{
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: It generates an inline style which would override that.

Comment: then change your element's padding directly with jquery!